# jquery click event back and forth

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, hidden

i'm working on my portfolio with my work contacts etc in jquery. i have class hidden which displays none and i can click on a button and the other things hides, but i can't go back and forth between the pages. how can i do like so? need help

---

```
let startPage = $(".container-startPage");
let about = $(".container-aboutPage");
let portfolio = $(".container-portfolioPage");
let contact = $(".container-contactPage");

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#about-btn").click(function() {
        about.removeClass("hidden");
        startPage.attr("style", "display:none");
        contact.attr("style", "display:none");
        portfolio.attr("style", "display:none");
    });

    $("#portfolio-btn").click(function() {
        portfolio.removeClass("hidden");
        startPage.attr("style", "display:none");
        about.attr("style", "display:none");
        contact.attr("style", "display:none");
    });

    $("#contact-btn").click(function() {
        contact.removeClass("hidden");
        startPage.attr("style", "display:none");
        about.attr("style", "display:none");
        portfolio.attr("style", "display:none");
    });

});
```

Comment: A Markup would help a lot. But just a suggestion, instead of using inline styling, try to use css with a class which has a style property of `display:none`. That way adding nd removing classes would be easier

Comment: What do you mean by "go back and forth between the pages"?  What specifically isn't working as expected?  Can you provide a complete example to demonstrate?

Comment: Use addClass('hidden') instead of attr()...

Comment: to change ("style", "display:none"); to addClass("hidden"); made it! thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the html code, but you can hide all container siblings. This is an Example. Hope it helps

```js
let startPage = $(".container-startPage");
let about = $(".container-aboutPage");
let portfolio = $(".container-portfolioPage");
let contact = $(".container-contactPage");

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#about-btn").click(function() {
        about.removeClass("hidden");
        about.siblings().addClass('hidden')
    });

    $("#portfolio-btn").click(function() {
        portfolio.removeClass("hidden");
        portfolio.siblings().addClass('hidden')
    });

    $("#contact-btn").click(function() {
        contact.removeClass("hidden");
        contact.siblings().addClass('hidden')
    });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="about-btn">About</button>
<button id="portfolio-btn">Portfolio</button>
<button id="contact-btn">Contact</button>
<div>
  <div class="container-aboutPage ">About Page</div>
  <div class="container-portfolioPage hidden">Portfolio Page</div>
    <div class="container-contactPage hidden">Contact Page</div>
</div>
```